# Select and Join from SQL table (Select statement + Hibernate code)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, join

I have the following two tables:

"STUDENT" and "SKILL" tables

```
STUDENT table
"id"         "name"
1             Peter
2              David
3             Mark

SKILL table
"id"    "id_student"    "skill"     "skill value"
1            1            height              180
2            1            weight              75
3            2            height              170
4            3            height              180
```

I would like to select "every student who have 180 as height, 75 as weight and "Peter" as a name".

The main thing that I need is the SQL statement but it would be very helpful as well if someone could tell me how to do this using Java + Hibernate (I mean how to create the Criteria object)

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you expect us to do your homework for you ? What good would it do to you ?

Comment: It's nice to think of my weight as a skill. Turns out, I'm pretty skillful.

Comment: I have tried this out a lot and I could not manage to do it. I can see myself getting the answer to this question ("every student who have 180 as height, 75 as weight and "Peter" as a name"). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without giving the *whole* game away, does this help?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student;

CREATE TABLE student
(id INT NOT NULL aUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES
(1,'Peter'),
(2,'David'),
(3,'Mark'),
(4,'Peter'),
(5,'Brian');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student_skill;

CREATE TABLE student_skill
(id_student INT NOT NULL
,skill VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,value INT NOT NULL 
,PRIMARY KEY(id_student,skill)
);

INSERT INTO student_skill VALUES
(1,'height',180),
(1,'weight',75),
(2,'height',170),
(3,'height',180),
(4,'height',170),
(4,'weight',75),
(5,'height',180),
(5,'weight',75);
```

Query 1.

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.height
     , y.weight 
  FROM student x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id_student
            , MAX(CASE WHEN skill = 'height' THEN value END) height
            , MAX(CASE WHEN skill = 'weight' THEN value END) weight 
         FROM student_skill 
        GROUP 
           BY id_student
     ) y
    ON y.id_student = x.id;
+----+-------+--------+--------+
| id | name  | height | weight |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Peter |    180 |     75 |
|  2 | David |    170 |   NULL |
|  3 | Mark  |    180 |   NULL |
|  4 | Peter |    170 |     75 |
|  5 | Brian |    180 |     75 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
```

...or alternatively, Query 2.

```
SELECT s.*
     , h.value height
     , w.value weight
  FROM student s
  LEFT 
  JOIN student_skill h
    ON h.id_student = s.id
   AND h.skill = 'height'
  LEFT
  JOIN student_skill w
    ON w.id_student = s.id
   AND w.skill = 'weight';

+----+-------+--------+--------+
| id | name  | height | weight |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Peter |    180 |     75 |
|  2 | David |    170 |   NULL |
|  3 | Mark  |    180 |   NULL |
|  4 | Peter |    170 |     75 |
|  5 | Brian |    180 |     75 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks Strawberry. Would it be possible to return only the ones who satisfy the requirements?

Comment: Of course, but that task has been deliberately left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Ok, I'll understand that :) Good thinking. I'll try that tomorrow morning (I can't try this now :( ) Many thanks for your help Strawberry!

Comment: I managed to select the data that I wanted. Thank you very much indeed! What I couldn't do it was to have this working on Hibernate :( Hibernate keeps saying that I can't have 2 inner joins with the same table. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I only know about the sql